# How to make 2 threads share data? (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently practicing Threads so I tasked myself to write a program that will create 2 threads. The first one will endlessly print a character and the second one will endlessly wait for input and then pass it to the first Thread. Then Thread #1 should print the passed character. Here's what I wrote:

```
public class A extends Thread {
                public char dif;
                Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (; ; ) {
                        dif = stdin.nextLine().charAt(0);
                        MyThread.setCh(dif);
                    }
                }
}
```

This thread takes input and then passes it to this one:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    public static char ch;
    public static void setCh(char cha) {
        ch = cha;
    }
    public static char getCh() {
        return ch;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(;;) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print(getCh());
        }
    }
}
```

And what happens in the `main()`:

```
MyThread endless = new MyThread();
       MyThread.setCh('$');
       A set = new A();
       endless.start();
       set.start();
```

However, this doesn't work as intended. No matter what I type, the program keeps printing `$`. Also for some reason the first time I type a character I get an Out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, the easiest way to approach this, is to use [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Effectively, in your example the thread, that receives character from `System.in` is `producer` and the thread that prints received character is `consumer`.

So, here is the code that achieves your goal:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Setup {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     BlockingQueue<Character> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
     Producer p = new Producer(q);
     Consumer c = new Consumer(q);
     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c).start();
   }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue<Character> queue;
   private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   Producer(BlockingQueue<Character> q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { 
         queue.put(produce()); 
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // set interrupt flag
     } finally {
       scanner.close();
     }
   }
   Character produce() {
      return scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
   }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue<Character> queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue<Character> q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { 
         consume(queue.take()); 
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
   }
   void consume(Character c) { 
     System.out.println("Received character: " + c);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually you have it is quite small delay in `Thread.sleep(300);`

Try to set sleep for a few seconds `Thread.sleep(5000);`. You have to type something before it will print previous char

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. A weird problem but that solved it nonetheless.